# how to pass nvarchar comma delimited input params to shawn SP

Tags: sql-server-2008

please, in plenty of articles on similar subjects, could somebody propose solution of passing nvarchar input parameters, comma delimited, to stored procedure beneath:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
merge MyTableName as target
using (select OutputColumn, LastName, RegID from MyTableName WHERE Column1 = '036A' AND  RowID=998) as source 
on ( target.RowID>998 and target.LastName = source.LastName)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            target.OutputColumn=source.OutputColumn;
    select * from MyTableName
END
```

Pls, what would be the simplest way to accomplish it? (sql server 2008 r2)

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to create a stored procedure with parameters? Did you check the documentation?

Comment: What Table/Column are you looking to filter with a delimited list?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if no one knows ... :)

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
    @comma_delimited_parameters nvarchar(max)
AS ....
```

or maybe

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
    @parameter1 nvarchar(10), -- comma
    @parameter2 nvarchar(10), -- comma
    @parameter3 nvarchar(10)
AS ....
```

**Cap**